# Gap between navigation and content?

Tags: html, css

Okay guys I am confused as to why there is a big gap between the black navigation and the content below?

http://database.gamingonlinux.com/

Answer (score 2):

Both `.left` and `.right` has a top-padding of `20px`.

Line 38 of your `style.css`:

```
.left
{
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: inline;
}

.right
{
    float: right;
    width: 83%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Oh arse thanks, that's what i get for using tutorials and not paying attention hah thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score. (You may want to do it for the rest of your questions too).

Answer (score 1):

because there is padding in your left and right div

```
.left {
clear: left;
float: left;
width: 15%;
padding: 20px 0;
display: inline;
}
.right {
float: right;
width: 83%;
padding: 20px 0;
display: inline;
}
```

remove padding:20px 0;